# How to find the correct value in excel column with one id but multiple value sin rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the results in an Excel sheet as follows:

```
Load Id Ship Ref Type
12345   monarch FALSE
                FALSE
                FALSE
                DRY
                FALSE
                FALSE
23456   MONARCH FALSE
                REEFER
                FALSE
                FALSE
```

I only need the ID and correct value (DRY or REEFER), so it would look like this :

```
Load Id Ship Ref Type
12345   Monarch DRY
23455   MONARCH REEFER
```

Comment: Your data is not clear. Is the whole data in one single cell or in different rows? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: sorry it is not typing my question correctly , i have load ID in column A , Ship Ref in column B, and Type in column C. Each ID has a type either dry or reefer but on multiple lines. for ex: ID = 123 in col A, ship ref " Monarch in col B, and Type in col C  AS false and DRY.I only want to see DRY

Comment: So, basically, you just need to remove the "FALSE" lines, and just keep whether each is a REEFER or DRY shipment?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Fill the blanks first ( Replicate the "Load Id", "Ship Ref" to all the columns ). 
[How to fill the Blanks?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/771-excel-fill-blank-cells-with-value-above.html)

Step 2: Filter on "Type" and then remove all (delete the rows) the "False"

You are done!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this piece of code to get the desired result. Please make sure to test it on a backed up data.

```
Sub delFalse()

    For i = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If (Trim(Range("A" & i)) = "") Then
            If InStr(1, Range("C" & i).Value, "FAL", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Else
            Do While (InStr(1, Range("C" & i).Value, "FAL", vbTextCompare) > 0)
                Range("C" & i) = Range("C" & i + 1)
                Range("C" & i + 1).EntireRow.Delete
            Loop
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

For the first time I came across this issue where `Range("C10").Value = "False"` gave me a `FALSE` even though `C10` is `FALSE`. Tested this in excel formula also and got the same thing. Hence I used the `INSTR` in the code.

Comment: Thank you! Really Appreciate it, I needed it urgently so, I ended up using Surya's suggestion last night, but I will definitely try this code for future.